# Формат года и месяца в Report Builder

Tags: sql-server

Когда я использую выражение `Year()`, то получаю год в формате YYYY. Как мне получить только последние две цифры в году? И как при использовании выражения `MonthName()` мне получать название месяца на английском языке (сейчас на русском) вне зависимости от языка системы?

Answer (score 1):

как вариант `substring(2,2,Year())`, ну или что-то в этом духе. К сожалению, нет возможности проверить.